# Not able to use htmlunitdriver in Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to use HTMLunitdriver  in eclipse.

I have written

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

All the jar files are added in the buildpath, but I'm getting the error "HTMLunit driver cannot be resolved to a type".

Can anyone provide any pointers on this?

Comment: are you using selenium 2.53 version

Comment: May be you did not import WebDriver and HtmlUnitDriver. If not then do it.

Comment: Hi,I'm using 2.53; import statements are also giving errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi arjun please downgrade to 2.52 it will surely work also i have figured it out why its not working

```
HtmlUnitDriver was a part of Selenium main distribution package prior to Selenium version
2.53. If you are using Selenium 2.52 or earlier you don't need to download and install 
HtmlUnitDriver, it is already there.

According to Selenium evolution strategy drivers should be separated from Selenium, 
and a driver release cycle should be synchronized with the target browser release cycle 
instead of Selenium release cycle. So this happened to HtmlUnitDriver too. It's not a part 
of the main Selenium distribution since version 2.53.
```

please go through the link for more info
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver
Also if you want to continue with 2.53 version please download the HtmlUnitDriver form here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases